# VBA VLOOKUP from different excel file with different names

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

Hi I do a vlookup in other excel spreadsheet in a different excel file. Now my problem is the name changes all the time.

```
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],[TEST2.xlsx]Sheet1!C1:C8,8,FALSE)"
Range("B2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Range("B2:B" & Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
```

So basically it looks in TEST2.xlsx for the data it needs and than it puts in a list in my original excel file. But the TEST2 gonna change all the time, everytime I'm gonna use this macro

How Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you require but if I'm right you could do something like this.
It's worth noting that it is not necessary to select cells first but rather you can reference them directly.

```
Sub lookupSub(dataFile)
Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],[" & dataFile & "]Sheet1!C1:C8,8,FALSE)"
Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Range("B2:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
End Sub
```

You can then call this as follows:

```
Call lookupSub("TEST2.xlsx")
```

Or if it works from within a loop you could do something like this:

```
For i = 1 To 10
    Call lookupSub("TEST" & i & ".xlsx")
Next i
```

Comment: Works just fine! Thanks! Can you now tell me how to make it remember the filename at the point I opened it with the macro 

so basically CALL lookupSub(File-I-just-Opened)

Comment: If the workbook is active then you could use :
Call lookupSub(ActiveWorkbook.Name)

Comment: Nope, there are many Workbooks open probably is the Problem. BUT, I open it in the macro with this before
`Dim MyFile As String
MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Workbooks.Open (MyFile)`
So could I CALL lookupSub(MyFile) ???

Comment: When you open a workbook it automatically becomes the ActiveWorkbook, so try using lookupSub(ActiveWorkbook.Name). It should work.

Comment: But the list with vlookup is supposed to created in the file where it looked up the data so it hast to first switch to the other workbook again, how is that working?